# NS3 error while installing

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-14.04, ns-3

I wanted to install the NS3 and during ./build.py the error showed up:

```
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/user/NS3repo/ns-3-allinone/ns-3-dev/build'
Build failed
     -> task in 'ns3-wifi' failed (exit status 1):
     {task 140583796598928: cxx wifi-mac-queue.cc -> wifi-mac-queue.cc.1.o}
     ['/usr/bin/g++', '-O0', '-ggdb', '-g3', '-Wall', '-Werror', '-std=c++11', '-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations', '-fstrict-aliasing', '-Wstrict-aliasing', '-fPIC', '-pthread', '-I.', '-I..', '-DNS3_BUILD_PROFILE_DEBUG', '-DNS3_ASSERT_ENABLE', '-DNS3_LOG_ENABLE', '-DHAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H=1', '-DHAVE_IF_NETS_H=1', '-DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H=1', '-DHAVE_PACKET_H=1', '-DHAVE_IF_TUN_H=1', '-DHAVE_GSL=1', '-DHAVE_SQLITE3=1', '../src/wifi/model/wifi-mac-queue.cc', '-c', '-o', '/home/user/NS3repo/ns-3-allinone/ns-3-dev/build/src/wifi/model/wifi-mac-queue.cc.1.o']
```

full log: https://pastebin.com/tAkph7UR
I've been following this tutorial: https://gnu-linux.org/installation-of-ns3-on-ubuntu.html
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on Virtual Box on the newest macOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've followed this tutorial and it's working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N3CMrfxbG4

Probably the problem was connected to the prerequisits. I've installed them like it was mentioned in the video:
`sudo apt-get install gcc g++ python python-dev mercurial bzr gdb valgrind gsl-bin libgsl0-dev libgsl0ldbl flex bison tcpdump sqlite sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-dev uncrustify doxygen graphviz imagemagick texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-generic-extra texlive-generic-recommended texinfo dia texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-extra-utils texlive-generic-recommended texi2html python-pygraphviz python-kiwi python-pygoocanvas libgoocanvas-dev python-pygccxml`

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04, python-pygoocanvas is no longer provided. The ns-3.29 release and later upgrades the support to GTK+ version 3, and requires these packages:

``` apt-get install gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0 python-gi python-gi-cairo python-pygraphviz python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-pygraphviz gir1.2-gtk-3.0 ipython ipython3  
```

Answer (score 0):

The current ns-3-dev has a minimal requirement of gcc-4.9, while the default gcc of Ubuntu 14.04 is still gcc-4.8, you might have to update your gcc. Check the note at [ns-3 installation guide for ubuntu](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation#Ubuntu.2FDebian) for a possible way to upgrade your gcc from 4.8 to 4.9.